# Unistalling and re-installing anaconda while anaconda environment was open - can't open cmd anymore

Tags: windows, cmd, anaconda

[image]
I uninstalled and re-installed Anaconda on my Windows 64-bit while I had an Anaconda environment activated in my cmd. Now, cmd won't open anymore, unless I launch it as administrator (restarting computer and removing Anaconda as Path variable doesn't help). My guess is that my cmd is "blocked" now, as I didn't do "conda deactivate" before uninstalling Anaconda (can't say with certainty though that this was actually the reason, but it coincides with cmd not opening anymore).
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

The error message from the screenshot appeared while uninstalling Anaconda, and also when trying to re-install it.

Comment: What error message shows when you try to open CMD?

Comment: No error message shows up. I click on 'open' and simply nothing happens. When I run cmd as administrator, I can type 'start cmd.exe' and open a new cmd, but it runs again the administrator version. Is there a way to specify in 'start cmd.exe' to specifically run it under a user account? If yes, I guess I should see in the administrator cmd what error message I get...

Comment: that is very weird. Try running it and open the task manager to see if anaconda or something is running on the back. Try closing them if u find something

Comment: That's a very good suggestion, however nothing named 'anaconda' appears there. Under 'Windows processes', there is some processes called 'Shell Infrastructure Host' and 'Console Window Host', but I assume those are standard things... not sure I can/should close those...